# Function defined by integral problem

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

I will write the problem : $\newcommand{error}{\operatorname{erf}}$

The "error function" is defined by the integral : $ \error(x) =  \frac {2}{\sqrt π} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \, dt$.

a) Show that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx$ = $ \int_0^1 \sqrt {-\ln y}\, dy$

b) If $ y =e^{x^2} erf(x) $ find the value of $ y' - 2xy $.

c) Write the function in serie Maclaurin.

d) Give a sum which calculates the value $ \error(1) $ with accuracy $ 10^{-2} $.

P.S. The "error function" is just an example name for the exercise, it's just a simple function.

Comment: Ok, so what's the question?

Comment: Can anyone solve this? I don't know even where to start and what to do...

Comment: For part $(a)$, substitute $u=x^2$

Comment: Tried.. still can't go to what it asks... can u post it? And do I need the erf(x) function to solve the a) question?

Comment: No, you don't; and please, post your working so it is easier for others to help

Comment: $ u = x^2 $ , $ du = 2xdx $ => $ dx = \frac{du}{2x} $ also in the integral if I power e with ln it goes away so I have $ \int_0^\infty -x^2 \, dx $

Comment: $ u = x^2 $ , $ du = 2xdx $ => $ dx = \frac{du}{2x} $ also in the integral if I power e with ln it goes away so I have $ \int_0^\infty -x^2 \, dx $ now I can say that $ \int_0^\infty -x*x \frac{2}{2} \, dx $ and replace with du so it goes $ \int_0^\infty \frac{-x}{2} \, du $ and we know from substitute $ x = \sqrt u $ so we have finally $ \int_0^\infty - \frac{\sqrt u}{2} \, du $

Comment: The first integral in (a) evaluates to $\sqrt \pi /2$

Comment: @JohnLou I don't think I have to calculate it... I have to find a way to transform the left part to equals to the right part.

Comment: I understand, but calculating it seemed to solve it for me

Comment: For part (c), what function is it talking about?

Comment: @JohnLou I think its talking about the error function,  erf(x).

Comment: I think I solved part c, and using a short form of that should help you find d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt \pi / 2$$

This is a common integral (look up Gaussian integral)

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{-\ln(y)} dy, y = e^x, dy/dx = e^x \to\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^x\sqrt{-x}dx$$
$$-x = u^2, dx/du = -2u \to \int_{\infty}^0-2u \cdot e^{-u^2} \cdot u du = \int_0^{\infty} 2u^2\cdot e^{-u^2}du$$

From here you can use Feynman's trick

$$\int_0^{\infty} 2u^2\cdot e^{-u^2}du = -2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt}e^{-tx^2}dx$$

at $t=1$

Then, using the gaussian integral,

$$-2\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 \sqrt t} =  \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 t^{3/2}}$$

And at $t = 1$
$$\sqrt \pi /2$$

FOR PART (B)

$$y= e^{x^2}\cdot erf(x)$$

First, let's find the derivative of $erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$

Assume $e^{-x^2} = f(x)$ and its antiderivative is $F(x)$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} (F(x) - F(0))$$

Clearly, the coefficient stays; as $F(0)$ is a constant, it is taken out. $F'(x) = f(x) =  e^{-x^2}$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} (F(x) - F(0)) = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \cdot e^{-x^2} $$

Using the product rule for derivatives,

$$y' = 2xe^{x^2} \cdot erf(x) + e^{x^2} \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \cdot e^{-x^2}$$

$$2xy = 2xe^{x^2}erf(x)$$

$$y'-2xy = 2xe^{x^2} \cdot erf(x) + \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} - 2xe^{x^2}erf(x) =\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} $$

FOR PART C

The maclaurin series is the taylor series at $0$

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^n(0)\cdot x^n}{n!}$$

where $f^n(0)$ represents the "nth" derivative, and $n=0$ is $f(0)$

$$f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$$
$$f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^x 1 -t^2/1 + t^4/2 - t^6/6 + t^8/24 - t^10/120... dt$$

Can you see the pattern? Are you familiar with the expansion of $e^x$? This is basically just substituting $-t^2$ for $x$.

Then it is

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-t^2)^n}{n!} dt = $$

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2n \cdot \frac{(-1)^n \cdot t^{2n - 1}}{n!}\right) \mid_0^x  = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2n \cdot \frac{(-1)^n \cdot x^{2n - 1}}{n!}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the exercise asks to prove that left part equals right part... don't think thats a solution for part a). I check part b) now.

Comment: The left and the right are both numbers. I have proved that those two numbers are the same. Perhaps there is a simpler way. I can't think of it now :(

Comment: Check part b) again... forgot to add erf(x) in the question.. its $ y = e^{x^2} erf(x) $ sorry...

Comment: I think i got part b now

Comment: Let me check... Thanks for helping.

Comment: Looks good and I understood all the solution. Thanks. So part B is solved.

Comment: @STUDENT_LIFE I think I got c and d as well

Comment: Hey thanks mate... I will read this later or tomorrow probably... Even though if its easy and u can write the d) answer also it would be great cause I don't have any similar problem... Thanks a lot for ur time.